# Cassandra Real Time Content Ranking Solution

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I would like to implement a real time content ranking system on cassandra 1.2  CQL 3.0

Example : Providing the top 10 comments on a news based on user vote

- user can comment a news
- user can vote +1 or -1 on each comment

Maybe 100, 1000, 10k, 100k comments by content

So what i need is to get real time (or 5min delay) the top 10 comments based on vote score

[real example youtube comment]

My solution is :

- storing vote counter on counter table (content_counter)
- create a rank table

create table content_comment_rank (
content_id timeuuid,
score bigint,
com_id timeuuid,
PRIMARY KEY (content_id, score, com_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC)

- all data of a content_id is stored on 1 ROW ordered by score desc
- I only have i this table comment with at least 1 vote

So what happen when a user vote

- SELECT score FROM content_counter where content_id='x' (R: 123)
- UPDATE content_counter SET score=score+1 (124) (or -1)

IN BATCH :

- DELETE content_comment_rank WHERE content_id='x' AND score=123 AND com_id='y'
- INSERT content_comment_rank (content_id,score,com_id) VALUES ('x',124,'y')

So having top 10 comments of a content is

SELECT * FROM content_comment_rank WHERE content_id='x' LIMIT 10

It's pretty easy BUT i'm not sure i'm doing well because :

- How to deal with replication and Concurrent vote

  Maybe by updating 1 time in batch each day (It's like that vote on video youtube is working)
- Maybe there is a better way....

We need "cluster ordering on counter table"..... (all done in 1 atom query) but doesn't existe (or not...)

What's your advice on my solution ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

@Sebastien Kondov

You are duplicating counter value (score) in **content_comment_rank** table. You may have mismatches between the Cassandra distributed counter table **content_counter** and the counter value in table **content_comment_rank**

To mitigate that you may want to write and read in this table with QUORUM consistency level but it has a cost on performance, for sure.

Now, it depends on how critical it is for you to have mismatches in counting in real time. If it is acceptable to have some % error rate then your solution is perfectly suitable. Afterward, in the background, you may run batches to re-synchronize **content_counter** and **content_comment_rank**.

*How to deal with replication and Concurrent vote*

--> On concurrent vote, **content_counter** table will provides strong consistency. For **content_comment_rank**, the last write wins

*Maybe there is a better way....*

You can read this article: http://nathanmarz.com/blog/how-to-beat-the-cap-theorem.html

The idea is:

1. Have a real-time process to save votes in **content_comment_rank** table, and accept some errors in the counting.
2. Have a batch in background that fixes any mismatch in counter, using **content_counter** table as source of truth to write data to another **correct_content_comment_rank** table. This batch process should be run frequently, but reading and fixing data only for the last past few hours
3. For queries on top 10 comments, you can merge results between **content_comment_rank** and **correct_content_comment_rank**

Comment: Thank you It's this kind of article that i was looking for

Comment: Welcomed. Hope that it'll will work out for you. Keep me updated if you devise a working strategy. I'll be interested by your implementation